# How to drop a row with an empty cell from a pandas dataframe but with 0 value?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, replace, nan

I have a dataframe which looks as follows:
[image]

It is shown as empty. But when I check the value

> df4.iloc[195]

it returns 0 of object type.

I want to remove it from my dataframe. I tried

> df4.replace(0, np.nan, inplace=True)

But it is still present as an empty cell with 0 value. I also tried replacing "" with

> np.nan

And I also tried using

> regex=True

However, the problem seems to persist. Therefore, I cannot covert the pandas dataframe into a numeric type. What would be a good way to solve this issue?

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with convert to `to_numeric`

```
df4 = df4.apply(lambda x : pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce'))
df4 = df4.dropna()
```

Comment: I got the same results as previous with df4=df4[df4.ne("")]

Comment: With the second option, I get a TypeError: arg must be a list, tuple, 1-d array or Series.

Comment: @HimalayaBirShrestha try the second one , and show us your dataframw without picture

Comment: I get a TypeError with the second one as stated above.

Comment: @HimalayaBirShrestha the best I can do please see the update

Comment: With lambda function, it seems to be working. Thank you very much. :)